# Why does my iOS app suddenly start to crash when opened?

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I've downloaded my iOS app to my (physical) iPhone, and at first it works perfectly, but after a few days or so (I'm unsure of the exact time frame) the app just crashes immediately when I try to open it. I've tried connecting it to XCode to see if it gives some sort of error, but there's nothing— the console is just blank. When I run the app on my phone again, it fixes the issue and the app works as normal, so I don't understand what the problem could be. If there's any code that would be helpful, please let me know— for reference, the libraries used are Firebase, Firestore, XLPagerTabStrip, and ios-Charts.

Comment: There is no issue with the libraries if it worked fine even once. There could be internet issue which you can troubleshoot by turning Wifi and Mobile data off. Or you check device memory.
Still, you need to add more information to track the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when you sign your code through XCode, it only lasts on the device for about a week. After that it won’t let you launch. If you want to get your app back, plug your phone back into XCode and rerun the project. Alternatively you can get it permanently on your phone if you buy into the Apple Developer Program and publish your app to the App Store.

Comment: Or, if you’re not ready to distribute through the store, use TestFlight builds are valid for 90 days.